# What distribution over X yields uniformly distributed distances between elements of X?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm curious if you can find a probability distribution over $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, such that the random variable $D = d(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, diam(\mathcal{X})]$, where $X,Y$ are i.i.d.

If this is even possible, what would that distribution look like? Are there constraints on $\mathcal{X}$ that make this possible/impossible?

Comment: What is $d(X,X)$ here? If it's just the distance, then please note that $d(X(\omega),X(\omega)) = 0$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: I meant the distance between two i.i.d draws of random variable X. Tried to clear up the notation with an edit.

Comment: But uniformly distributed on what? A priori $d(X,Y)$ can take any non-negative value, and there is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb R_+$. Perhaps if we assume that $\mathcal X \subset \mathbb R^d$ is bounded (i.e, it's diameter is finite), then we might ask whether there exists $X,Y$ independent with the same distribution such that $d(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,diam(\mathcal X)]$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @DominikKutek yes, that’s what I meant.